# Samba shared folder RAID 1

Tags: server, samba, raid, webmin

On my Ubuntu Server 20.04 system I set RAID1 with 2 devices.
How can I make my RAID devices a Samba shared folder?

Comment: Yo do not. You share folders not drives. RAID 1 makes your 2 drives have 1 volume correct?

Comment: Yes  RAID1 makes 2 drive like 1, half of them for backup. I can not found my drivers location for create folder inside driver. Any idea ? @David

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Server. the situation is as follows. I used 2 physical drives for RAID 1. I know that RAID1 normally uses one of the 2 disks of equal capacity and takes backups of the first disk to the other disk. My question is this. Currently RAID1 is active. I want to create a Samba shared folder, but the location to be saved must be my RAID disks. I couldn't do it. While creating the shared folder, I could not find the location of my RAID disk on the ubuntu server. @David

Comment: I think I understood my problem. RAID1 is active but not mounted. :((

Comment: Hey cool. It would be useful for others to see the issue is closed if you would write an answer to your own question and select it as the correct answer.  Can't hurt do describe how you actually solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem. After creating a RAID array, we need to mount the partition we created, that's all.

Creating a new location for raid with the mkdir command

```
sudo mkdir /media/any-name
```

then mount it with RAID

```
sudo mount /dev/your-raid-name /media/any-name
```